# C# use embedded icons

Tags: c#

I'm changin the tray icon to display a information, and I'm storing all icons in a folder in my desktop so I'm doing this to change the icon to the icon with the same name as the variable

```
TrayIcon.Icon = new Icon(@"C:\Users\LL\Desktop\Icones\" + iconname);
```

Now I would like to embend the icons im my project, how I can do the same thing?  i tryed to do this but didn't work

```
TrayIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources. + iconname;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TrayIcon.Icon = Resource.ResourceManager.GetObject(iconname) as Icon;
```

and sometimes better:

```
 TrayIcon.Icon = Resource.iconname;
```